# onPress fires more than once when using keyboard

Tags: javascript, android, react-native

I am developing an app for Android and I have a Touchable Opacity which fires more than once. This touchable opacity is a separate component.

Here is the button component:

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import {View, Text, TouchableOpacity, Animated, Easing} from 'react-native';

export default class CustomButton extends Component {

    constructor(props) {
        super(props);
        this.state = {
            loaded: false
        };
        this.focusIn = this.focusIn.bind(this);
        this.focusOut = this.focusOut.bind(this);
    }

    componentDidMount() {
        this.animatedValue = new Animated.Value(1);
        this.setState({loaded: true});
    }

    focusIn() {
        Animated.spring(this.animatedValue, {
            toValue: this.props.toValue
        }).start()
    }
    focusOut() {
        Animated.spring(this.animatedValue, {
            toValue: 1,
            friction: 3,
            tension: 40
        }).start()
    }

    render() {

        const animatedStyle = {
            transform: [{ scale: !this.state.loaded ? 1 : this.animatedValue}]
        }

        return (

            <Animated.View style={animatedStyle}>
                <TouchableOpacity onPress={this.props.onPress} activeOpacity={1} style={this.props.buttonStyle} onFocus={this.focusIn} onBlur={this.focusOut}>

                        <View style={this.props.buttonWrapper}>
                                <Text style={this.props.buttonLabel}>{this.props.buttonName}</Text>
                        </View>

                </TouchableOpacity>
            </Animated.View>
        );
    }
}
```

And here is the button in my App.js:

```
//the function
increaseQty(){
   this.setState({ selectedQty: this.state.selectedQty + 1 })
}

<View style={styles.qtyHolder}>

 <CustomButton
  buttonStyle={styles.qtyButton}
  buttonWrapper={styles.buttonWrapper}
  buttonLabel={styles.buttonLabel}
  buttonName="-"
  toValue={1.1}
  onPress={()=>this.decreaseQty()}
 />

<Text style={styles.qtyTextStyle}>{this.state.selectedQty}</Text>

<CustomButton
 buttonStyle={styles.qtyButton}
 buttonWrapper={styles.buttonWrapper}
 buttonLabel={styles.buttonLabel}
 buttonName="+"
 toValue={1.1}
 onPress={()=>this.increaseQty()}
/>

</View>
```

This button is inside a scrollview. It fires exactly 4 times when I pess return key on the keyboard and OK button (middle button) on the D-Pad

**Edit:**

Is it good to use debouncing? And does it impact the performance? I've found loadash debounce package and it works just fine